# Parsing XM returns URI is not absolute

Tags: java, soap, parsexml

I am trying to parse the following soap response, but the code returns following exception

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1095)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.toSource(JAXB.java:306)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(JAXB.java:220)
    ......
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchFlightsResponse xmlns="ElsyArres.API">
     <SoapMessage>
         <Username>Test</Username>
         <Password>Test</Password>
         <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
         <ErrorMessage />
         <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
         <AppVersion>8.0.3</AppVersion>
         <Request>
             <Departure>BER</Departure>
             <Destination>LON</Destination>
             <DepartureDate>2014-10-18</DepartureDate>
             <ReturnDate />
             <NumADT>1</NumADT>
             <NumINF>0</NumINF>
             <NumCHD>0</NumCHD>
             <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
             <CarrierList />
             <FareClasses />
             <Providers />
             <WaitForResult>true</WaitForResult>
             <NearbyDepartures>false</NearbyDepartures>
             <NearbyDestinations>false</NearbyDestinations>
             <RROnly>false</RROnly>
             <MetaSearch>false</MetaSearch>
        </Request>
        <Response>
             <SearchFlightId>140408111958-02-11428-310</SearchFlightId>
             <Roundtrip>false</Roundtrip>
             <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
             <Flights>
                <Flight>
                <Outbound>
                    <CarName>Test Airline</CarName>
                    <CarCode>_2</CarCode>
                    <DepName>Berlin</DepName>
                    <DepCode>BER</DepCode>
                    <DestName>London</DestName>
                    <DestCode>LON</DestCode>
                    .....
```

**Code**

```
       SOAPMessage sm = response;
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        sm.writeTo(out);


        this.results = (SearchFlightsResponse) JAXB.unmarshal(sm.toString(), SearchFlightsResponse.class);
        System.err.println(">" + results.getSoapMessage().getUsername());
```

**Response classes**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SearchFlightsResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchFlightsResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "SoapMessage")
    private SoapMessage soapMessage;
    .....

@XmlRootElement(name="SoapMessage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SoapMessage {
    @XmlElement(name="Username")
    private String username;
    @XmlElement(name="Password")
    private String password;
    ....
```

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "ElsyArres.API", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.myProject.wegolo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Answer (score 3):

XML Namespaces - `xmlns` attribute should follow the URL convention such as "file:", "classpath:", "http://", "ftp://", "db:".

In your case it is not.

see  http://openrules.com/rulesrepository.htm

Comment: so whats your suggestion to solve the issue? the response is received from a remote server.

Comment: try unmarshaling by changing the xmlns to proper format first.

Comment: For those, like me, who are wondering "but it used to work!" https://www.w3.org/2000/09/xppa, https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/05/24/deviant/